# Populate fields after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that allows the user to pay via credit card or paypal using radio buttons and when they click on each one respectively - the correct form loads via ajax.

My problem is: after the new form is loaded (via `.html()`) all my jquery doesn't work. For example the price of a donation is a radio field and on change it populates a span in order review. After the form loads all this doesn't work.

I'm also using [floatlabel.js](http://clubdesign.github.io/floatlabels.js/) which doesn't work on the loaded form either.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbhfycsp/1/)

**HTML - Donation Amount**

```
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="3000"><span class="radio-span">$3000</span>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="1800"><span class="radio-span">$1800</span>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="500"><span class="radio-span">$500</span>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="360"><span class="radio-span">$360</span>
    <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="180"><span class="radio-span">$180</span>
<input type="radio" name="amounts" value="other" id="other"><span class="radio-span radio-span-other">Other</span> <input type="text" name="other_amt" class="other-amt"/>
```

**HTML Payment Method**

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-cc" name="method" value="creditcard"><span class="radio-span">Credit Card</span>
<input type="radio" class="radio-paypal"  name="method" value="paypal"><span class="radio-span">Paypal</span>
```

**HTML - Order Review (this is in the ajax loaded form)**

```
<div class="order-review">
<span class="amount"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery - Populating span in order review**

```
    $("input[name=amounts]").change(function (e) {

    if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
        $("input[name=other_amt]").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
        $("input.hidn-amt").val( '$'+$(this).val());
        $("span.amount").val( '$'+$(this).val());
    });
    }else{
       var selected = $("input[name=amounts]:checked");
        $("input.hidn-amt").val( '$'+selected.val());
        $("span.amount").val( '$'+$(this).val());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since new fields are being loaded in via AJAX, the eventing bindings are being lost. You can use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to prevent this.

```
 $(document).delegate('input[name="amounts"]', 'change', function (event) {
   // code here
 })
```

I believe you can use `.on()` as well, in a similar format, provided you use the document as the selector.

Comment: this doesn't help - I want the ajax fields to be populated if the user has already clicked on the amount

Comment: Considering another person gave the same answer as me, try explaining your question more so it's clear what you're asking, or set up a demo.

Comment: ok it works that you can select an amount after ajax load and it populates the span - is there anyway to have the span pre populated on load? - youre code is a better option - lemme try edit the question and maybe set up a fiddle

Comment: On the left sidebar of jsfiddle there's a giant navigation link that says "Ajax Requests". Give it a read :P

Comment: i need to load an element via php

Comment: ok i figured it out - I put the overview on the static form without loading it with ajax - everything works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery runs before the AJAX request completes, so it does not apply to the new elements which are fetched later.

You can wrap your entire bindings in a function wrapper, maybe call it `initForms()`, and call that function after the `.html()` code.

There are more ways to bind elements automatically using the `$("body").on` syntax of jQuery if you want to have a look at.